# Entity framework - Intensive CPU load on Add

Tags: performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I have small project with about 20 tables where row entries are of minimal contents size but there are plenty of relationships between the tables.

I'm using code first with all my navigational properties being set as virtual.

Today I've noticed that when I'm adding entity to DbSet with Add method, and entity has about 6-7 foreign keys, adding roughly 2000 entities just to DbContext (without doing SaveChanges) takes about 30 seconds and CPU is stuck at 100%.

Is there a known performance hit when entities have too many virtual navigational properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably EF is just tracking changes and because your entities are NOT tracking entities, ef spends time on searching for dependant entities.

My first try would be to try to make your entities "change tracking entities", you do so by making ALL your properties virtual, not only navigation properties.

Comment: Do you have any reference page where I can read more about all virtual properties?

Comment: http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2011/12/05/should-you-use-entity-framework-change-tracking-proxies/